# Will trustrelationship break if a role is recreated with same rolename in IRSA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

If there is RoleA in account 123 which is trusted by RoleB in account 345. if RoleA is recreated would that break trust relationship for RoleB and need to be trusted again?
Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will break if you are using the role as the principal because under the "friendly names" (which you see in ARNs) it uses [unique identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids). If that happens, you will see the ID in the trust policy instead of the ARN. You will have to edit/update the policy to fix it.

Comment: Can confirm, found the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-roles
The red box says "if you delete the role, then you break the relationship"